# Need help converting a merge function from R to Python, shape of resulting df is the same but losing more rows in Python after dropping duplicates

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, merge

I believe the merge type in R is a left outer join. The merge I implemented in Python returned a dataframe that had the same shape as the resulting merged df in R. Although when I had dropped the duplicates (df2.drop_duplicates), 4000 rows were dropped in Python as opposed to the 50 rows dropped when applying the drop duplicates function to the post-merge R data frame

The dataframe I need to merge are df1 and df2

```
R:
df2<-merge( df2[ , -which(names(df2) %in% c(column9,column10))], df1[,c(column1,column2,column4,column5)],by.x=c(column1,column2),by.y=c(column2,column4),all.x=T

Python:
df2 = df2[[column1,column2,column3...column8]].merge(df1[[column1,column2,column4,column5]],how='left',left_on=[column1,column2],right_on=[column2,column4]
```

df2[column1] and df2[column2] are the columns I want to merge on because their names in df1 are df1[column2] and df1[column4] but have the same row values.

My gut tells me that the issue is stemming from this portion of the code that I might be misinterpreting:  -which(names(df2) %in% c(column9,column10)

Please feel free to send some tips my way if I'm messing up somewhere

Comment: Make certain to [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and spent some time to make the question readable. We are all using our free time to answer questions on stackoverflow, so properly editted questions where time spent is visible have a much greater chance of getting an answer. :-)

Comment: Understood I wasn't aware of that link and I appreciate you sending it to me :) Won't happen again!

Comment: Have you tried `which(names(df2) Negate(%in%) c(column9,column10)` instead of `-which(names(df2) %in% c(column9,column10)`? Which output is right: The one from R or the one from Python?

Comment: The one from R is right and I'm trying to have the output in Python match that of R's

Comment: Okay, but why are you doubting the R code `-which(names(df2) %in% c(column9,column10)` then?

Comment: I'm actually not doubting the R code. What I meant to say by that is I'm doubting my Python interpretation of that piece of R code

Comment: In the R code, is `df2` missing a closing square bracket and `which` missing a closing parenthesis? Please also show how you drop duplicates in R.

Comment: Yes you are right I forgot to add them in the question, it's updated now. and in R the distinct() function was used. But I've examined the problem enough to know that the issue isn't with the distinct() or drop duplicates funcition. I think in R when it says which(names(df2) %in% c(...), I can't seem to find a Python equivalent of searching through the df2 values for which there are values within the columns in c(column9,column10) that are not null. I think I have to use isin() in my merge somehow because isin() is the equivalent to %in% apparently

Comment: It's going to be near impossible to help with this without specific data examples. Can you find a couple rows that Python drops but R doesn't and post them?

Comment: Interesting you use `dplyr::distinct` and not `dplyr` for the `left_join` and `select` of columns. Your current code is base R version. So to drop duplicates in base R: `unique(df2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the list subset of columns in Pandas is [no longer recommended](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-with-list-with-missing-labels-is-deprecated). Instead, use [**`reindex`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to subset columns which handles missing labels.

And the R translation of `-which(names(df2) %in% c(column9, column10))` in Pandas can be `~df2.columns.isin([column9, column10])`. And because [**`isin`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) returns a boolean series, to subset consider [**`DataFrame.loc`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```py
df2 = (df.loc[:, ~df2.columns.isin([column9, column10])]
         .merge(df1.reindex([column1, column2, column4, column5], axis='columns'),
                how='left', 
                left_on=[column1, column2], 
                right_on=[column2, column4])
      )
```

Comment: Wow this worked perfectly. Can't thank you enough. You sir are a gentleman and a scholar.